# How do I print on the console if a user use a regex?

Tags: python, syntax-error, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I've written a regex so when a user writes in the chat "Kosovo", my bot will send him an audio and a text.

```
    regex = "k+o+s+o+v+o"
try:
            nick = update.message.from_user.username
            if re.search(regex, contLower):
                    chatid = update.message.chat.id
                    audio1 = "/Users/rikardo/Documents/ANGELO/Programmare/Prove di basi/Mat/SUONI/KosovoBello.ogg"
                    update.message.reply_audio(audio=open(audio1, "rb"))
                    update.message.reply_text("Stay tuned, @PadriFibra")
                    return
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

return
```

Then I added this:

```
print(strftime("%H:%M:%S -")," "+(nick)+" triggered KosovoBello")
```

and the result was this:

```
    regex = "k+o+s+o+v+o"
try:
            nick = update.message.from_user.username
            if re.search(regex, contLower):
                    chatid = update.message.chat.id
                    audio1 = "/Users/rikardo/Documents/ANGELO/Programmare/Prove di basi/Mat/SUONI/KosovoBello.ogg"
                    update.message.reply_audio(audio=open(audio1, "rb"))
                    update.message.reply_text("Stay tuned, @PadriFibra")
                    print(strftime("%H:%M:%S -")," "+(nick)+" triggered KosovoBello")
                    return
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

return
```

But when I try to start the bot, the console says this:

```
    $ python3 /Users/rikardo/Documents/ANGELO/Programmare/Prove\ di\ basi/Mat/prova.py 
  File "/Users/rikardo/Documents/ANGELO/Programmare/Prove di basi/Mat/prova.py", line 107
    regex = "k+o+s+o+v+o"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It would be good if you could share the code exactly as it is, since indentation matters in python.

Comment: Could you include some of the code above this line too? Also, please fix the indentation and make sure it looks exactly like your actual code. (E.g., is the first line of the code you shared truly indented more than the line after it?)

Comment: Also, you seem to think it was the addition of the `print` line that caused the error, but that certainly doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: you need to fix your indents - e.g. first line should not be indented. Also, what are your imports/methods? Is regex already a method?

Comment: I solved my problem. I don't even remember how, lmao. I'm sorry if I didn't explain better the problem, it was my first question on stackflow.

Answer (score -1):

This is not exactly correct.  By specifying '+' after each character you allow matching of things like kkooosoovvvvvvo :-)

Instead, you should just use the exact string you want:

```
regex="(kosovo)"
```

I'd also suggest including case variations

```
regex="(kosovo|Kosovo|KOSOVO)"
```

or just using IGNORECASE so that every variation is covered.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I want to allow matching of things like "kkkkoooosssssooovvvo".